# How to replace a value within a dataframe if it is bigger or smaller than the cell in the row above?

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the values in a data frame column conditional on the previous values in that column. If the value being checked increases or decreases by more than 0.15, then replace that value with `NA`.

However, I not sure how to implement this. I think it would require an `if-else` statement, but I'm not sure what that would look like.

For example, how would I apply the rule to `col1` in the data frame `DF` below? `NA` should replace the `"4"` in `col1`, so the `"5"` should be compared against the `"9.2"` (i.e., the last value in `col1` not replaced with `NA`).

```r
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
col1 <- c("9.1", "9.2", "4", "5", "9.2")
col2 <- c("7", "7.5", "8", "8.3", "8.4")

DF <- data.frame(ID, col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this should solve the problem for values in `col1`:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
col1 <- c("9.1", "9.2", "4", "5", "9.2")
col2 <- c("7", "7.5", "8", "8.3", "8.4")

DF <- data.frame(ID, col1, col2)

DF$col1 <- as.numeric(DF$col1)

absDiffToPrevious <- c(0,abs(diff(DF$col1)))
aboveThresh <- absDiffToPrevious > 0.15

DF$col1[aboveThresh] <- NA
```

Your `DF` then looks like

```
ID col1 col2
1  A  9.1  7.0
2  B  9.2  7.5
3  C   NA  8.0
4  D   NA  8.3
5  E   NA  8.4
```

Comment: I think OP would want to have 9.2 instead of NA in the last value of col1.

Comment: Thanks for the solution -  I have applied your code to my DF and it works for the large part. However, there is an issue I want the code to work from the last correct observation. In the example that would be col1 B, so if the value doesn't meet the requirements for that one it gets an NA but then I want the next value to be compared to col1 B - as it the last correct observation. Any idea on how to achieve this?